# How to filter some specific data in Microsoft PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, excel-import, powerapps-selected-items

I am creating a Powerapp which needs to import data from a excel sheet and once those data loaded, I want to edit some of data.
I used Gallery and Gridview and managed to extract data from that excel file. I used edit forms, but didn't work for me.
The fields on the table are FirstName,LastName,Email and ManagerName.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to retrieve data to edit? I have 500+ records.
2. I want to filter the users who are under same manager.

Here is the sample data table of mine.
[image]

Any advice really appriciate. I tired several methods but didn't success. Seeking your support. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You use the excel-connector to work with your data?

```
Filter(
     YourExcelData,
     DropDownContainingManager.Selected.Value = Manager
)
```

Now PowerApps will filter all records and show the records where the manager is equal to a value you selected from a dropbox. (You have to specify something to filter...)

Comment: **NOTE:** You will likely run into [Delegation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwiErbYtRdA) issues if you transfer this method to ANY other datasource besides Excel. Also beware that the `LastName` field in your example has a leading space (" ") in many of the names. You'll want to either clean this up BEFORE inserting into the Excel sheet OR us the PowerApps `Trim()` function.